# Is it possible to keep the file position using less.sh from neovim?

Tags: neovim

I added following to my `init.vim` in order to preserve the last opened file position:

```
if has("autocmd")
    au BufReadPost * if line("'\"") > 1 && line("'\"") <= line("$") | execute "normal! g'\"" | endif
endif
```

However I can still enter into `insert` mode which is not desirable.

So I tried to use `less.sh` script instead, which is really like the **`less`** command. However this does not store file position.

Is there a way to have these two functions combined (less + save pos)?